# How I connect gorm with postgres?

Tags: database, database-connection, grails-orm

I need your help, because my app can´t connect with postgresql (docker),
this is the error:

> 2022/12/13 11:04:29 C:/Users/Jose Gomez/Desktop/GoPrj/go-gorm-postgresql/db/connection.go:15
> [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=localhost user=jose database=gorm`: failed SASL auth (FATAL: la autentificaci�n password fall� para el usuario �jose� (SQLSTATE 28P01))
> 2022/12/13 11:04:29 failed to connect to `host=localhost user=jose database=gorm`: failed SASL auth
> (FATAL: la autentificaci�n password fall� para el usuario �jose� (SQLSTATE 28P01))
> exit status 1

and my dbconnection is:

```
package db

import (
    "log"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var DNS = "host=localhost user=jose password=mysecretpassword dbname=gorm port=5432"
var DB *gorm.DB

func DBConnection() {
    var error error
    DB, error = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(DNS), &gorm.Config{})
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatal(error)
    } else {
        log.Println("DB Conectada!!!")
    }
}
```

I need connect this dbconnection

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean containers by `docker system prune -a` and volumes by `sudo rm -rf docker/volumes/db/data`